# Set letter spacing of last character in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently creating an input field that requires letter spacing, but if the last letter is spaced it shifts everything out of alignment... I was just wonder if there would be anyway of finding the last character of the input field which will be the 13th character with jquery or JavaScript and setting the letter spacing to 0.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How does it shift everything out of alignment? Please show some code. If this is really an input field, you cannot have different `letter-spacing` for different characters, as it’s one element with plain text content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/). It wraps characters in HTML, allowing you to manipulate them more finely with CSS.

Comment: How would that help? Wrapping characters in HTML elements doesn’t even work in input fields (where no markup is recognized).

Comment: Are you trying to style the user's input, or are you trying to style the field's label / placeholder text? I wouldn't recommend attempting the first, but if it's the second you could use this [InField Labels plugin](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) and then apply Lettering.js to your label. If that still doesn't help, it'd be helpful to see some code so I can better understand your issue.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to trim the trailing space right??

If so you can simply trim the input field value every time it changes. Here is the JQuery solution.

$.trim(MyInput.value);